# Issues with updating a fresh remote git repository

Tags: git

I have a local git repo and a remote git repo. I inadvertantly added a large number of large files to both my local repo and my remote repo. I spend some time with BFG removing the files on a mirror of the local repo, and then I pushed the fixed mirror to the local repo, and now I am trying to push this fixed, smaller, local repo to the remote server. I am able to push the new local repo to the remote, but can't push any new commits to the remote repo.

The local repository shows this for the log:

```
$ git log
commit 529eb17a427e396da9138f29e5d9e56628f2fe63 (HEAD)
Author: Mark Phillips <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Thu Sep 24 15:59:07 2020 -0700

    Changed wsgi.py

commit 2160caf1f435d8a4208eba2620afc19c7e913ab5
Author: Mark Phillips <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Wed Sep 23 22:28:53 2020 -0700

    Added Welcome, user, and link to admin pages for admins.

commit 5b5b162c14cc92fa0a75b261b9a4793fc0032ed3
Author: Mark Phillips <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Wed Sep 23 17:19:30 2020 -0700

    set up SSL in apache config and added it here. Made some small changes to DocumentAdmin and DocumentAdminMetadata in the display of file fields.

commit ec963707ac6e2acebf33014187d6c6e95f07d763
Author: Mark Phillips <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Sun Sep 13 19:26:21 2020 -0700

    Added auth_required decorator to all memorabilia views.

commit 73b46111a767e91e44951b12164d68d7276b29de
Author: Mark Phillips <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Sun Sep 13 19:10:21 2020 -0700

    Added a basic login process and password retrieval system. No registration.
```

I removed the old remote repo and create a new one using `git init --bare` on the local machine. Same name as before, and same location.

On the local machine, I run `git push -f origin master`, and the files are uploaded to the remote repo. When I run git log on the remote repo, I get:

```
$ git log
commit 9cc1a44121993baa5ffb03f0a7a539797b308a3d (HEAD -> master)
Author: Mark Phillips <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Sun Sep 13 19:26:21 2020 -0700

    Added auth_required decorator to all memorabilia views.

commit 36215d7a6d8b16d1e8e4faa0d5b9ec6d769f09d6
Author: Mark Phillips <xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>
Date:   Sun Sep 13 19:10:21 2020 -0700

    Added a basic login process and password retrieval system. No registration.
```

Why are the three latest commits on the local machine missing from the remote machine? If I create another commit on the local machine using

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Some message"
git push origin master
```

I get the message "All is uptodate" or something similar, and nothing is pushed to the remote machine.

Why can't I push changes to my remote repo?

One other fact, is that the remote git repo involves a symlink. I ran out of space in the original file system, so moved the remote repo to the new drive called BlockStorage1.The repo is at ~/git-repo/project.git, and the ~/git-repo/ -> /mnt/BlockStorage1/git-repo.  This symlink has been working for months for other repos, both new and old, so I don't think it is the problem/

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Can you try this way once?

`1. git clone the remote repo
2. git checkout -b <branch>
3. git add and git commit the updated code to this new branch
4. create a pull request to master and merge`

Comment: Can you give me a little more explanation? I don't understand what you are saying or how it works.

Comment: Clone whatever code you have on your remote repo to your local repo. This can be done by `git clone`. That will mostly comprise code till "Added auth_required decorator to all memorabilia views." commit.

Then checkout a new branch in your local repo from this master branch which you cloned. This can be done by `git checkout -b <branch_name>`.

Comment: Then add your new code, which consists of these 3 commits, "set up SSL in apache config and added it here. Made some small changes to DocumentAdmin and DocumentAdminMetadata in the display of file fields.", "Added Welcome, user, and link to admin pages for admins.", "Changed wsgi.py"

Then push the code to the remote repo, this can be done by `git push -u origin <branch_name>`

Then create a pull request from <branch_name> to master branch

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will have to study the git docs a little more to understand your solution. Can you explain where my logic went wrong? I edited my local repo to remove all the big files. I then deleted the remote repo and tried to create a new remote with the code in my local repo. I am the only one using these repos and code, so I have no issue with making drastic changes like deleting the remote and starting again with the code from the local repo. Thanks!

Comment: What is the active branch in your local repo ? You can see that with `git branch`.

Comment: The branch is * master